# IBM cloud Pak for business automation workflow

Tags: ibm-cloud, workflow, ibm-cloud-infrastructure, ibm-cloud-functions, ibm-cloud-tools

In **IBM cloud Pak for Business automation workflow** I have created a process, now I need to start the process or extract the process data using postman or REST. But the IBM is not allowing me to fetch the data, there is a authorization error.

I was expecting the data from the POST request

[Click here to see the post method](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XsV1s.png)

Error:

```
<!--
* Licensed Materials - Property of IBM
*
* 5725-L63
*
* (C) COPYRIGHT IBM CORP. 2020 All Rights Reserved.
*
* US Government Users Restricted Rights - Use, duplication or
* disclosure restricted by GSA ADP Schedule Contract with
* IBM Corp.
-->

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>

<body>
    <script>
        // Redirecting to the new index.jsp (login page with notifications), keeping URL parameters and hash
        window.location.replace("/auth/index.jsp" + window.location.search + window.location.hash);
    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.